# ¿Cómo eliminar caracteres de un String en un intervalo de tiempo para que parezca una animación?

Tags: vb.net, string

¿Cómo puedo eliminar caracteres de un string aplicando un Timer? Es decir, que cada un segundo elimine un caracter "■", como en este ejemplo:

```vb
"■ ■ ■ ■ ■"     'Primer tick
"■ ■ ■ ■"       'Segundo tick
"■ ■ ■"         'Tercer tick
```

... y así sucesivamente, para que en ejecución parezca una animaciónn

Esto es lo que hice para la prueba:

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim anterior As Integer
    Private Sub btnAnimar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAnimar.Click
        n = 0
        Timer1.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        n += 1
        anterior = 11 - n
        Console.WriteLine(anterior)
        lblAnimText.Text = lblAnimText.Text.Remove(anterior, n)

        Console.WriteLine(anterior)

        Console.WriteLine(n)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español! Aunque tu pregunta parece clara, deberías de añadir el código que tienes hecho hasta ahora porque no sabemos si tu problema es quitar un carácter o hacer el temporizador. Tienes que poner el código que has intentado. Lee la ayuda para ver [cómo hacer una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: ¿Cual es el problema con el código que tienes actualmente? ¿Cual es la razon de tu pregunta?

Answer (score 1):

Esta seria mi solución, no es la mas versátil, pero se acopla a lo que pides y creo que te puede servir de ejemplo.

```vb
Dim _arrayManejadoraCadena As Char()
Dim _timer As System.Timers.Timer
Dim _index As Integer

Sub New()

    InitializeComponent()

    animacionLabel.Text = "EsteTextoDesapareceLentamente"
    ''2 segundos!
    segundosTextBox.Text = 2000 

End Sub

''Aquí viene la madre del cordero
Private Sub ejecutarBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ejecutarBtn.Click

    ''Deshabilitamos el botón para que no pueda usarse
    ejecutarBtn.Enabled = False

    ''Vamos a convertir la cadena en una lista de carácteres
    _arrayManejadoraCadena = animacionLabel.Text.ToArray()

    ''Establecemos el timer
    _timer = New Timer(Convert.ToDouble(segundosTextBox.Text))
    AddHandler _timer.Elapsed, AddressOf timerHandler
    ''Iniciamos el timer
    _timer.Start() 

End Sub

Private Sub timerHandler(sender As Object, e As ElapsedEventArgs)

    ''Lo primero que hacemos es parar el timer

    _timer.Stop()

    ''Comprobamos si hemos terminado ya

    If (_arrayManejadoraCadena.Length = 0) Then

        ''Hacemos es dispose del timer

        _timer.Dispose()

        ''Volvemos a habilitar el botón, utilizando beginInvoke

        ejecutarBtn.BeginInvoke(Sub()
                                    ejecutarBtn.Enabled = True
                                End Sub)
        ''Nos vamos!

        Return
    End If

    ''Redimensionamos la cadena
    Array.Resize(_arrayManejadoraCadena, _arrayManejadoraCadena.Length - 1)

    ''Convertimos el array de caracteres en un String
    Dim stringResultado = New String(_arrayManejadoraCadena)

    ''Asignamos el nuevo valor de la cadena al label
    ''Utilizamos el metodo beginInvoke ya que desde el subproceso que se ejecuta el timer
    ''no tiene acceso a UI

    animacionLabel.BeginInvoke(Sub()
                                   animacionLabel.Text = stringResultado
                               End Sub)

    ''Volvemos a poner en funcionamiento el timer

    _timer.Start()
End Sub
```

Suerte!